# Keycloak access token not working for dcos-cli

Tags: keycloak, dcos

I am trying to login to dcos-cli (OAuth enables).
When i type dcos auth login -> this gives me a URL

If i open the URL in browser and enter credentials a code (token) is being generated, using which i am able to log-in into the cli.

This has to be automated so i am sending a curl request

```
curl -s --data \
  "grant_type=password&client_id=dcos&username=dcosuser&password=<>" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
  https://ip:port/auth/realms/DCOS/protocol/openid-connect/token \
| jq -r '.access_token'
```

But using this access token i am not able to login.
Can anyone please help.

Comment: Perhaps reading over the docs and blog in the [Authentication section](https://github.com/dcos/community/wiki/DC%5COS-FAQ#authentication) of the community wiki might help

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by a java program which gets the access code from the keycloak-server .and then runs the `dcos auth login`.

The java code does a GET to `https://<ip>/login?redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob`

And then from the page extract the "action" attribute from the returned page and then from a POST request to the URL obtained from the "action" with other parameters like password.

```
Ex:  https://<ip>:<port>/auth/realms/DCOS/login-actions/authenticate?code=erpkJ0BaLcp9VV2eTkY_a9xdpeNNzc375Ic7vHxhcMg.1b1461c6-51cd-484e-8c0e-a615600b7156&execution=8ad82be0-2471-40b1-b7e0-3192e0c8a381
Post parameters : username=dcosuser&password=<pass>&login=Log+in
```